# Kernel and image of matrix: What are they? Why do they exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, intuition, motivation

I've been trying to get an understanding of the Kernel of image of matrices. I'm studying them in college right now, but the problem is, while I can find a ton of resources on how to find them given a matrix by following steps, I haven't been able to find anything that explains what they are intuitively. Also why have them in the first place?

I hope someone who understands these concepts better can help me.

Comment: Usually, we say the "Null space" of matrix, rather than the "Kernel" of matrix.
Also the "Column space" of matrix rather than "Image" of matrix.
Kernel and Image are using while talking linear transformation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix corresponds to a linear function. Generally speaking, for a function $f:X\to Y$, the kernel of $f$ is $f^{-1}(0)$ and the image is $f(X)$.

Here $Y$ is a group, ring, field, vector space etc so it has a zero element $0\in Y$.

Note the kernel $f^{-1}(0)$ is a subspace (subgroup, etc) of $X$ and the image $f(X)$ is a subspace of $Y$.

There is a nice sequence of maps
$$0\to\ker f\to X\to \operatorname{im} f\to Y.$$

Comment: So the kernel would be the whatever you need to input to 'f' in order to get 0 (or 0 vector)?

Comment: @Elior : Precisely. It’s everything that gets mapped to zero.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm a little confused by the sequence of maps at the end of you question (I may be interpreting it wrong). Is that showing the relationship between 0 and the ker(f), and then the ker(f) being part of the domain X, then same for im(f) being part of codomain. Why is there an arrow from X to im(f)? How does the domain relate to the image?

Comment: The arrow you mention is the action of the map $f$ of $X$ onto its image. The arrows before and after that can be thought of as simple inclusion maps. Try googling “exact sequence” for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well they exist because they kind of define the output given the input or if there is a unique solution of an inverse problem etc.

They both defines sets. Kernel defines a set of vectors such that take one of them and multiply it with your vector, you end up with 0 vector. Image on the other hand defines a "target set". Take any vector that can be multiplied with your matrix and multiply them. You cannot end up with a vector that does not belong to the image of your matrix.

Comment: What is an example of a use for the kernel (in mathematics or any other field)?

Comment: @Elior: First isomorphism theorem.